# Show that a set $A$ is transitive $\leftrightarrow$ $P(A)$ is transitive. Where $P(A)$ is the power of $A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that a set $A$ is transitive  $\Leftrightarrow$ $P(a)$ is transitive. Where $P(A)$ is the power of $A$.

Let   $x\in P(A)$ 
$\Rightarrow$ $x\subseteq A$
 with $a\in x$ $\Rightarrow$ 
$a\in A$ $\Rightarrow$ (Hip) 
$a\subseteq A$ $\Rightarrow$ 
$a\in P(A)$ $\Rightarrow$ 
$x \subseteq P(A)$

Now the comeback:

Let $x \subseteq A$ with $a \in x$ $\Rightarrow$ $x \in P(A)$ $\Rightarrow$(Hip) $x \subseteq P(A)$ $a\in P(A)$ $\Rightarrow$ $a\subseteq A$

My struggle is with the comeback. I don´t think is exactly correct. Could anyone check it? Thanks guys.

Comment: can you include definition of transitive?

Comment: transitivity is usually spoken of for a relation on a set, how are you using it here?

Comment: Transitive: if $x \in A$ $\Rightarrow$  $x \subseteq A$

Comment: It's hard to follow what you're trying to do.  You should put in some more words.  In the "comeback" aren't you supposed to prove that if $P(A)$ is transitive then $A$ is transitive, that is $x\in A\implies x\subseteq A?$  If so, you seem to be assuming what you want to prove.

Comment: The proof is so terse it is incoherent.  What does "Hip" mean?

Comment: @Mustang.  The relation is $\in$.

Answer (score 1):

Conversely when P(A) is transitive.
Assume x in A.  Thus {x} subset A, {x} in P(A).
By transitivity, {x} subset P(A).
As x in {x}: x in P(A), x subset A, QED.